Jest test error [Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one]
I keep getting error [Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one] though I have wrapped my test in a QueryClientProvider. What do I do wrong.
describe("Selector", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();

    render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={({ error }) => <div>Something went wrong: {error.message}</div>}>
           <Selector content={content} setLanguageCallback={() => {}} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </QueryClientProvider>,
    );
    screen.debug();
  });

  it("Is there a hello test text", () => {
    expect(screen.getByText("Hello")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  
}); 

